# How rigorously can boundary conditions on statistical power of stratified analysis vs. pooled analysis be defined?

Tags: statistical-power, pooling

I spend a lot of time thinking about conditions under which various kinds of analyses perform well. To some degree I am hoping NOT to specify too many specifics here (because part of what I am interested in is the degree to which such any statements made can generalize), but for arguments lets say I have x=1-3 variables of interest, ~10x as many possible confounders, and ~100-1000x samples.

Currently, my approach is to compute a variety of descriptive statistics, look at collinearity between predictors etc. on the front end. This has the effect of streamlining downstream model building because I can often frame a fairly good first draft model based on the descriptive stats. I also have "hunches", *e.g.* I might find myself thinking that "a pooled analysis with an appropriately constructed contrast is likely to outperform stratified analysis for these data."

But, what I keep returning to is this idea that I could streamline this still further if I could formalize or generalize conditions under which a pooled analysis will/won't outperform stratified (and ideally why). Such an answer would not have to generalize over all datatypes to be useful; for instance if one said, "for over-dispersed count data, [this rule]" that would still be helpful.

Comment: @whuber any thoughts, or practical suggestions?